# Is there a difference in performance when having code in a <script> tag or from a .js file?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I have a few hundred lines of javascript code that is only going to be used on a single page. However, I am unsure if I should put the code into an external .js file or keep it in a  tag. I believe the script tag would have to load before the rest of the page could load, but the .js file would have to load side by side with the html and could become slower in the long run.

I understand the performance difference between the two options are close to negligible (down to milliseconds with a good network connection), but I would really like to know if there is and which one would be faster.

When I say 'faster', I am talking about the page download speed, how long it takes before the code actually runs, if there could be an impact on the speed of code as it start running, or if there is any other delay that I am not aware of.

Also, I have my code wrapped in a jquery

```
$(document).ready()
```

I believe that would have an impact on when the code would start running in this situation.

Thanks

Comment: Impossible to say. It would depend on how big the files were, how much they could compress, how many other resources exist that might interfere with parallel downloading, and so on. The differences, as you have already pointed out, are negligible so don't waste your time worrying about them.

Comment: Refer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223918/is-it-better-to-put-the-js-code-on-the-html-file-or-in-an-external-file

Comment: If you are already including jQuery, why are you worried about performance hits in how you include your own code? It's a moot point.

Comment: As Quentin said, you'd literally have to measure in several different situations to know what the advantage was.  An external JS file allows better caching, but likely takes a big longer to load the first time.

Comment: @Mathletics - jQuery is likely already cached from prior pages/prior sites.  So, it's probably only coming from the cache and if done right, coming from a CDN too.

Comment: Thanks @Jatin My choice of words through google were poorly chosen when I was searching for an answer.

Comment: I asked the question from pure curiosity, and if there was anything I'm missing that I don't know about.

Comment: I didn't think about the server caching the extra file, so with that in mind I think I am going to go with an external js file.

Comment: For large javascript projects I always use external files.  For small snippets, I put them at the end of the html file right before the end of the body tag.  I've never seen a performance problem using external files, and I have some fairly large javascript projects that get up over 10,000 lines of code, and I often use jQuery along with my javascript, which in itself is over 9,000 lines of code.  I wouldn't really worry about it nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there's no "correct" answer.

If you want to try to [leverage](http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html) the user's browser to cache your javascript file, you can create a .js file for your code.

If, on the other hand, you don't want to rely on the user's cache, go for including the whole script in `<script></script>`: this will save you an HTTP request, which is an average of a few hundreds of bytes (I never really counted them, but that's the length of an average request, give or take.

There are some other ways of improving the "loading" time, such as compressing the javascript code (i.e. removing the spaces used for indentation, using short variable names, and so on). Some good services can be found [online](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/).

Another way for having your code run "faster", is optimizing it: it is likely that, if you didn't pay that much attention, your code may have some inefficient behaviors. You can go through your code to find such behaviors, and change them. I can't really tell you what to look for, since there are too many different aspects in this. Most browsers try to optimize the code while running it, but it's not a bad thing to write code that is already optimized. If you want to run some benchmarking tests, you can use [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/)

Comment: If I were to put the javascript into an external file and call it in the top of the html page, would the page still render just as fast as if I called the javascript file at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Not really sure about that: I don't know what the browser's priority is: you can fins it out by looking at the requests made by your browser  (chrome and firefox both let you do that, but I'm on my smartphone at the moment). Assuming that it's using a "first found, first get" rule, you should add your file at the top of the page. Also, the general rule is to include your scripts inside the `head`

Comment: @StevenRogers: shortening variables names has no measurable influence on the download speed whatsoever, unless you would care about nanoseconds, which are one thousandth of one thousandth. It will only lead to a lesser readability and clarity of the Javascript. Also, minifying Javascript files with comments can easily lead to broken scripts. You just shouldn't care about it, Steven. It's not worth the few milliseconds, which nobody will notice anyway. Focus on proper work flow, and clarity for later times/the next web dev that has to work with your code. That will save time!

Comment: Actually, that's not entirely true @FrankConijn: let's say that the script is using N variables, each of them with a name M characters long, and say that each of the variables is used K times in the script. Finally, let's call V the download speed of the user (B/s). Assuming N<26, every variable can be replaced with 1 character, and the time saved shortening the variables is t=(N*(M-1)*K)/V. Now, fair values could be N=15,M=5,K=10,V=0.25*10^6 (that's my downloading speed :( ), and we get t=3ms. That's just for shortening the variables, without considering all the spaces used for indentation!

Comment: So, the time saved with these "optimization" should be kept into account when working with non-trivial scripts. Also, any decent js compressor will remove the comments, making the "comments problem" not a problem at all. This being said, I agree with you when you say that most users won't even notice the difference of a few ms (especially for those with a decent Internet connection), but still he wanted to know how to get "extreme" optimizations, and my answer was all about that :)

Answer (score 0):

If the JS file is used across multiple pages, it is better to have it in a separate file for caching purposes. If it is only used in a single file, a script tag would be slightly faster because it would save an HTTP request.

Comment: Why are you talking about JS across multiple pages? The question makes it clear that isn't the case here. Saving an HTTP request might not make things faster, even if more data is transferred overall, if the files are large enough then parallel downloads might result in faster results.

Answer (score 0):

With $(document).ready() your code will run until the whole page download finishes, and yeah the page will download faster if you put all the js code in a separate file, both the page and the js will be downloaded in parallel. And is a good practice to have you js code in separate files to favour caching or to have those files in a dedicated CDN.

Comment: "the page will download faster if you put all the js code in a separate file" — That might not be true. The overhead of the additional HTTP request could end up slowing it down over all.

Comment: yeah there is an added cost of issuing another http request, but the cost is less when you had the chance to compress, minify or cache the js in the browser.

Comment: You can compress and minify the JS when it is embedded in the HTML. Caching won't give you an advantage the first time you load it, and HTML documents can be cached too.

Comment: yes, it will not give you an advantage the first time you load it, but what if you reuse that script in 3,4,5 other pages, like someone said there is no "correct" answer in my case i prefer having both things separated in order to reuse code and have a cleaner html, and to have the ability to host those files in other place dedicated to static content like a CDN for example.

Comment: The question makes it clear that the script is *not* being used across other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some practices that you can implement to improve page loading speed.

**1.** Put javascript in a separete file will make the browser cache the javascript file, so it will wouldn't load the same piece of code over and over again.

**2.** You can also put the javascript before the ending `</body>` tag, so you avoid blank screen while browser are trying to interpret your javascript file because in that point the page layout already visible to the user.